# Table view with static cells and dynamic table view on one View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller that contains a dynamic table with all the `<UITableViewDelegate>` and `<UITableViewDataSource>` stuff set. Now, I have another table which has static cells. It's in the same view, but it is not the same table. Since I have all the table view delegates implemented, the static cells obviously don't show up. How can I fix it so that I have both table views?

Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tag`property of `UIView` to solve your issue.

Assign tag like this programmatically. You can assign `tag` in XIBs too.

```
tableView1.tag = 1;
tableView2.tag = 2;
```

Now in your delegates check for this `tag` property of `tableView` and write conditional code.

```
if(tableView.tag == 1) {
 // Code for cell corresponding to first table
}
else {
 // Code for cell corresponding to second table
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what exactly is the conditional code? For example, how do I specify if a cell should be static?

Comment: Updated my answer for conditional code. And there will be two types of cell with different properties. right? What do you mean by static or dynamic here? Cells can be default or custom I guess.

Comment: So there's one table view with just static cells, (ones that are not populated via the data source), and dynamic cells which are populated from a data source. I know how to write that conditional, but what do I write for creating cells which are static, and whose properties are already set in Storyboard

Comment: How are you populating your static cells?

Comment: I created them in Storyboard, and created outlets for the content in my View Controller

Comment: I think, you just need to write the most common code that we write using UITableViewCell. And sets its value to be displayed in cellForIndexPath delegate method. Have you tried this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44250/discussion-between-san-and-carpetfizz)

Answer (score 1):

Give each table a tag and in the `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method check for the tableview and then assign cells appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the tag method, you could keep a property to each of the TableViews in your View Controller and then check the reference in the delegate and datasource methods, e.g.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.staticTableView) {
        //handle click on static tableview cell
    } else if (tableView == self.dynamicTableView) {
        //handle click on dynamic tableview cell
    }
```

}

I think this is a little bit cleaner as you don't have to memorize the tags of your tables (or use constants or an enum to track them).